# React Native: How to wrap content the height of Scrollview?

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview

I'm trying to create a filter button. I need the Scrollview because the categories comes from an API and it wouldn't fit in a single screen size. I need the height to wrap content because the Scrollview is horozontal but it did not work when I used `alignSelf:'baseline'`. I could wrap the ScrollView around a View but the button height is not static.

This is how the screen looks like:

[image]

```
<ScrollView 
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} 
    horizontal={true} 
    style={[GlobalStyle.ListTab]}>
    {listTab.map(item => (
        <TouchableOpacity key={item.id} 
            activeOpacity={0.8} 
            onPress={() => setStatusFilter(item.name)} 
            style={[GlobalStyle.ButtonTab, status === item.name && GlobalStyle.ActiveButtonTab]}> 
            <Text style={[GlobalStyle.TextTab]}>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}
</ScrollView>
```

GlobalStyle.js

```
ListTab: {
    alignSelf:'baseline',
    marginBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: red,
},
ButtonTab: {
    minWidth: DEVICE_WIDTH / 3.6,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    backgroundColor: white,
    marginHorizontal: 10, 
    elevation: 10,
    alignSelf:'baseline', 
},
TextTab: {
    fontSize: 16,
    alignSelf:'baseline', 
},
ActiveButtonTab: {
    backgroundColor: purple,
},
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the view to expand to fill the content? Try to put a `flex: 1` on the scrollview container. I think that's what you're referring to. If not, can you give a little more explanation?

Comment: @JoelHager Sorry, my English is bad. Basically I want the height of the Scrollview to be wrap around the child. I edited my post to show how the problem looks like

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you added `flex: 1` to the scrollView it would expand to fill the screen the way you want. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @JoelHager What I meant is I want the height of scrollview to only take the height of button, not the whole screen

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can achieve output using the following way:

- Wrap `ScrollView` in another `View` and give height to that `View`
- Using  [flexGrow](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props.html#flexgrow) for `ScrollView` style

```
ListTab: {
    flexGrow: 0,   //<---- here
    alignSelf:'baseline',
    marginBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: red,
},
```